# Seem to have a viewport issue on Samsung mobile browser only

Tags: html, css

My website displays well on every other browser I have tried,
Except Samsung.
Here is a link https://timiakogun.com

On Samsung browser.

[image]

On chrome (as expected)

[image]

How do I fix it?